# Upload a track to Soundcloud via Flash without FileReference

Tags: api, actionscript, file-upload, soundcloud

I want to use Soundcloud-AS3-API (https://github.com/dorianroy/Soundcloud-AS3-API) for uploading a track to Soundcloud.
The Api works as expected, when you use FileReference and choose a track from your computer to upload, BUT I already have the audio data in my Flash project, because I use the microphone to record something. So my sound fileformat for uploading is ByteArray from the mic-recording.

**Question**: Is it possible to upload sound without FileReference, but with "standard" URLLoader or anything else Flash based?

All tries from me failed so far, but I don't know if it's just wrong adjustment of the parameters, of if it's just not possible without FileReference or some other "Multipart-Uploader", Soundcloud declares to be needed.
If it works the next problem would be to get any "progress" event, because URLLoader doesn't sent ...

Anyone any experience with this or any idea?

Thanks in advance,

Oliver

Answer (score 1):

You should use the simpler JS SDK to authorize and then get the auth token with it's help: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/javascript-sdk

As for the upload itself, you might want to try out the MultipartURLLoader class for that, it works ok at least with a few minute recordings.
http://code.google.com/p/in-spirit/wiki/MultipartURLLoader

I might not be aware of some official Adobe-made alternative, I guess.

Comment: Thank you. But with MultipartURLLoader, there still would be the problem, you don't get any progress events, so you need extra technology. Then JS SDK would be the easier approach indeed.

Comment: I don't know how to get the token out of the JS SDK. I see nothing like a "getAuthToken" function or similar, how could I get that information?